# GUICtrlCreateDate set date in autoit

Tags: autoit

I have a date control in my autoit gui:

```
$Date1 = GUICtrlCreateDate("", 48, 56, 186, 21)
```

When I run it, it starts on today's date. But when I compile it and run it later it will start on the day it was compiled. Can someone tell me how to have it always start on today's date?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
$Date1 = GUICtrlCreateDate(@YEAR & "/" & @MON & "/" & @MDAY, 48, 56, 186, 21)
```

It worked for me once I compiled it and set my computers date manually to a different day and then run it again...

Answer (score 0):

You may also use

```
#Include <Date.au3>
$date = GUICtrlCreateDate(_NowDate(), 48, 56, 186, 21)
```

This is the way I do it and it works well for me.